# Too many arguments error

Tags: asp.net, datetime, session

Hi i'm getting an error when using this code

```
Session("formatdate") = Left(drv.Row("booking_status"), 10)

Session("formatdate").ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

Can anyone suggest anything? I'm trying to convert my session to a friendly date format but it won't work

This is the error

```
Too many arguments to 'Public Overridable Function ToString() As String'.
```

Thanks

Jamie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Left(drv.Row("booking_status"), 10)` returns a String.

There is no overload for String.ToString() that takes a String as a parameter. You might want to try something like:

```
Session("formatdate") = DateTime.Parse(Left(drv.Row("booking_status"), 10)) _
                                .ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a tool to convert from C# to VB, so here you go...

```
Dim formattedDate As String = [String].Format("{0:C}", Session("formatdate"))
```

Answer (score 0):

As Justin [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857458/too-many-arguments-error/3857475#3857475), there is no overload for `String.ToString()` that takes a string as a parameter. However, there are several [overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tostring.aspx) for `DateTime.ToString()`, [one of which](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) does take a string. 
In order to take advantage of this method, you need to convert your `Session("formatdate")` to a `DateTime` object:

```
Session("formatdate") = Left(drv.Row("booking_status"), 10) = Left(drv.Row("booking_status"), 10)

DateTime temp;

// Ensure date parsed successfully
if (DateTime.TryParse(Session("formatdate"), out temp)
{
   string formattedDate = temp.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
}
```

Note that if you know the format that `Session("formatdate")` will be in, you can use `DateTime.TryParseExact()` instead of just `TryParse()` to ensure that the date is parsed according to the proper format.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store a DateTime in Session("formatdate") then use `((DateTime) Session("formatdate")).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");`